# How to create narrowed typescript interfaces from existing interface which has optional fields?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface with optional field(s) like this one:

```js
interface Config {
  foo: Foo
  bar?: Bar
}
```

In a function I check whether they are not `undefined`, then call another function:

```js
function doSomething(config: Config) {
  // ...
  if(config.bar) {
    const result = calculateSomethingUsingFooAndBar(config)
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

Of course inside the if's scope the bar is narrowed which means we know that it exists and is not optional anymore. So I want to call the function `calculateSomethingUsingFooAndBar` without defining a new interface just for making `bar` required, but telling the compiler that when this method is called it should already have `bar`. Also if I want to call the function from somewhere else, where the `bar` was not narrowed, that should cause a compile-time error, as we are not sure if `bar` was defined.

```js
function calculateSomethingUsingFooAndBar(config: Narrowed<Config>) {
   // config.bar (and every other optional field) is defined here, we can use it.
}
```

Is there such a thing or a neat but not hacky workaround for this? I have checked the [advanced typescript types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) but could not figure out if they can help me or not.

Comment: check `Omit`/`Pick`, but in general - try to design interfaces/types without optional parameters: have a base config and extend an interface to add additional properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt

```
type RequiredConfig = Required<Config>;

function calculateSomethingUsingFooAndBar(config: RequiredConfig) {
   // config.bar (and every other optional field) is defined here, we can use it.
}
```

Comment: Ahh perfect, I did not see that Typescript had untility types!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Required<T>` type for this. It makes all properties of T required.

See: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredt

Comment: I think you added an irreleant link